# How to sort the array of objects based on nested property in Aurelia/Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, aurelia

I have to sort the array of objects by its nested properties. More precisely, I have to sort the **payment** derived from **service.payments** object based on **payment.paymentDate** property.

Is there a way to customize the sort converter code or modify the html so that I can sort the payment based on the paymentDate?

See the code below for more details:

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="payment of service.payments | sort:payment.paymentDate:'ascending'">
    ${'dashboard:contracts.desc.custPayment' & t: {
        value: payment.value,
        currency: payment.currency,
        date: formatDate(payment.paymentDate)
    }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my SortValueConverter code:

```
export class SortValueConverter {
toView(array: {}[], property: string, direction: string) {

let sorted = [].slice.call(array).sort((a, b) => {
  if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1;
  if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
  return 0;
  });
  return direction === 'ascending' ? sorted : sorted.reverse();
  }
}
```

Here is the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

based on the sort valueConverter you provided below, your HTML should look like this:

```html
<li repeat.for="payment of service.payments | sort:'paymentDate':'ascending'">
    ${'dashboard:contracts.desc.custPayment' & t: {
        value: payment.value,
        currency: payment.currency,
        date: formatDate(payment.paymentDate)
    }}
</li>
```

aslo: why not just using array sort function regulary?

```
export class SortValueConverter {
toView(arr: any[], property: string, direction: string) {

  const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a[property] - b[property]));
  return direction === 'ascending' ? sorted : sorted.reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the data screenshot I just uploaded, you will notice that sort:'paymentDate':'ascending' will not work. Also regarding your second suggestion, it will not work as argument has no slice method, so conversion to array is needed. But thanks however for trying to help :)

Comment: you are trying to compare dates? but you have strings in your data. convert the data to Date first, then the sort will work. `service.payments` is an array - so you don't need to slice.. just sort normally. in fact: your question is not really an aurelia question but rather understanding the exact data structure that you have.

Comment: The solution you are providing is not working unfortunately, I tested and tried all the scenarios. If I don't use [].slice.call(array) I'm getting "array.sort is not a function error" , so this does the trick. Regarding the data, I am comparing strings, which are later formatted to Date and displayed. I think the only issue is that I'm trying to sort by a nested property on the same line where I'm iterating through service.payments, so rather my sorting logic needs to be modified somehow, or my HTML should be extended/formatted differently.